Eclipse Setup issue with include library
On MacOS using Eclipse with g++ and c++17 dialect.
When trying to build my project there is an issue with the library.
The library isnt found, which in turn doesn't let me include basic headers such as "<iostream>".
This Problem doesn't occur using XCode, but we are forced to use Eclipse so it isn't an option to switch IDEs.
**** Incremental Build of configuration 
Debug for project Aufgabenblock_2 
**** make all 
Building target: Aufgabenblock_2 Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker g++  -o "Aufgabenblock_2"  ./Fahrzeug.o    
-l/Users/MyName/boost/libs ld: library '/Users/MyName/boost/libs' not found 
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [Aufgabenblock_2] Error 1 "make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.


You seem to have several different issues mixed up. -l/Users/MyName/boost/libs is simply wrong, but we cannot tell how your build script got this command because you show us none of your setup. OTOH <iostream> has absolutely nothing to do with it. If you have a problem with including <iostream>, it's a different problem.
